# May Formatter not be used on Strings?

Tags: java, string-formatting

I was stumped when I checked the result of following code:

```
public class StringBuilderTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder matrix = new StringBuilder();
        Random r = new Random();
        Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
        for (int j=0;j<10;j++) {
            String[] strings = new String[10];
            StringBuilder formatString = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
                formatString.append("%-10.5s");
                strings[i] = new Integer(r.nextInt(10)).toString();
            }
            formatString.append("\n");
            matrix.append(formatter.format(formatString.toString(), strings));  //gives me unexpected result: 1+2+3+..+10=55 lines of 10 cols of random ints
            //matrix.append(String.format(formatString.toString(), strings));  //gives me expected results: 10 lines of 10 cols of random ints
        }
        System.out.println(matrix.toString());
    }
}
```

I get 55 (!) lines of 10 columns each of neatly formatted integers: row 1, then row 1 and row 2, then row 1, 2 and 3 and so forth. It seems that `formatter.format` works incrementally.

When changing `formatter.format` to`String.format` the result is as expected: 10 lines of neatly formatted integers.

The Java reference states that

> Strings may be formatted using the static method `String.format`.

But there is no indication that `new Format().formatter(...)` may *not* be used for Strings. (And if I use the constructor `Format(Appendable matrix)` everything works as expected.)

What`s the explanation for this erratic behaviour?

Comment: I don’t know to what extent this is just an academic exercise, but that is very much not the right way to use Formatter.  As Leo Aso points out, `new Formatter()` creates an implicit StringBuilder, so there is no reason to create any StringBuilders explicitly.  And there is no benefit to building a String array;  you can simply pass each number directly to the Formatter inside your loop.

Comment: @VGR You may be correct about the academic exercise. As for your second point, it is sometimes necessary to build a String and formatter array - when the number of columns is not known at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both cases are actually [expected behaviour](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)). The `Formatter` class has an internal buffer (by default a `StringBuilder`) to which it appends the result of every call to `format`, and the `toString()` method returns the entire contents of the buffer. So the first time you call

```
matrix.append(formatter.format(formatString.toString(), strings));
```

It adds row1 to the formatter buffer and then appends it to the matrix. Call it again and it adds row 2 to the buffer, but now the buffer contains row1 and row2, so both rows get added to the matrix, which now has row 1, row 1, row 2. This goes on and ends up adding 55 rows in total.

```
old matrix    +    buffer    =    new matrix
                   1              1
1                  12             112
112                123            112123
112123             1234           1121231234
...and so on
```

On the other hand, if you just call String.format, it produces the same output as `formatter.format`, but does not append it to any buffer. That way, on each loop iteration, only the last row created gets appended to the matrix, which is the expected result.

TL;DR: `formatter.format` adds formatted row to internal buffer, then outputs whole buffer, while `String.format` simply outputs formatted row.